# Read Local file from Remote Location via SSH in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssh

I want to access a local file which is located on a device via a remote server location via SSH.

The local file is in this directory

```
/Desktop/applications.csv
```

and the IP address of the machine it is located in is `192.168.1.1`  and user is `user1`

How do i read it from a remote location using SSH in Ruby on Rails?

I tried doing this but it fails

```
hash = Digest::MD5.hexdigest(File.read("ssh  user@192.168.1.1 /Desktop/applications.csv"))
```

Not sure how to go about it. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [use ruby Net::SSH to read a remote file via sudo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9840573/use-ruby-netssh-to-read-a-remote-file-via-sudo)

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into [SSHKit](https://github.com/capistrano/sshkit)? It lets you run commands on remote machines, via ssh.

As an example:

```
require 'sshkit'
require 'sshkit/dsl'
include SSHKit::DSL

on '192.168.1.1'
  within "/Desktop/" do
    with rails_env: :production do
      rake "read_applications"            
    end
  end
end
```

And the 'read_applications' rake task would do the File.read and whatever else was required.

EDIT:

Does it know what user you're authenticating with? Might need to add the user like this:

```
on '192.168.1.1'
  within "/Desktop/" do
    as :user do
      # do something
    end
  end
end
```

And change :user to be your username. There's loads more examples on the Github page.

Comment: interesting but when i run this, it tells me ssh::authenticationfailed. even though i put in the current password for the user. Any reason why?